# how to use variable content as a part of a other variable name?

Tags: php

i want to use a variable content (value) as a part of a variable name before the output

this is my code in other file:

```
<?php $vidooid1="fk16zv6mw2jj"; ?>
<?php $vidooid2="eztx3n90w8xs"; ?>
<?php $vidooid3="eztx3n90w8xs"; ?>
<?php $vidooid4="eztx3n90w8xs"; ?>
<?php $vidooid5="eztx3n90w8xs"; ?>
<?php $vidooid6="eztx3n90w8xs"; ?>
<?php $vidooid7="eztx3n90w8xs"; ?>
<?php $vidooid8="eztx3n90w8xs"; ?>
<?php $vidooid9="eztx3n90w8xs"; ?>
<?php $vidooid10="eztx3n90w8xs"; ?>
```

and this is the code in the actual file:

```
<?php $titlenumber="1"; ?>
<?php $vidoo="https://vidoo.tv/e/"; ?>
```

and this is the echo final result:

```
<?php echo $vidoo; ?><?php echo $vidooid; ?>
```

I want that when I change the value that is inside the `$titlenumber` then that it is also changed in number that is next to the `$videoid` <----just here (i want to rename the string by using titlenumber)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be far better implemented using [arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

e.g.

```
<?php
$vidoos = array(
  "fk16zv6mw2jj", 
  "eztx3n90w8xs",
  "eztx3n90w8xs",
  "eztx3n90w8xs",
  "eztx3n90w8xs",
  "eztx3n90w8xs",
  "eztx3n90w8xs",
  "eztx3n90w8xs",
  "eztx3n90w8xs",
  "eztx3n90w8xs"
);

$titlenumber = 0;
$vidoo="https://vidoo.tv/e/";

echo $vidoo.$vidoos[$titlenumber];

$titlenumber = 3;
echo "<br/>"; //line break, just for demo
echo $vidoo.$vidoos[$titlenumber];
?>
```

Note that arrays start their indexes at 0 by default, so if you can start titlenumber at 0 too, you can do it simply like I've shown. If not, shift the array as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65992031/5947043)

BTW you don't have to write a new `<?php` on every line. Just write it once at the start of the section of PHP, and close it once with `?>` at the end. Lines in between only need to end with `;`.

Comment: thx but you understand me from other perspective, i dont want to get a bulk of links , what i want is changing $videoid(some number) dinamicaly

Comment: by changing something in your code i got what i want but i get other id instead what i want

Comment: `what i want is changing $videoid(some number) dinamicaly`...well that's separate to this problem (I think)...what is it which triggers the change of ID, exactly? This code will collect whichever ID is mentioned in $titlenumber. That's hard-coded in my example...but perhaps you want to get $titlenumber from somewhere else, like user input, maybe? You need to clarify what you mean.

Comment: `by changing something in your code i got what i want but i get other id instead what i want`...to fix this, we'd have to see exactly what code you have got now, and exactly what ID you're getting (and what you wanted instead). We can't fix vague descriptions of code. Please edit your question.

Comment: i fixed it thx , i forget that the array starts with 0, i added a nulled line just above the first id

Comment: Like I said in my answer, if you don't want it to start at 0 there is a better approach than that - see what AliveToDie did with array _unshift. Glad you fixed it though

Comment: the problem what is , is dont know to implement alive to die code with your code

Comment: Huh? It's the same apart from the array name

Answer (score 0):

You can use concatenation as the following example shows:

```
$iterator = 1;
$variableName = 'vidooid';

$vidooid1 = 'some value';

echo ${$variableName . $iterator}; // outputs 'some value'
```

As the others said before, you should learn how to use arrays with PHP. The above shown solution is okay, but should not be used when you can use arrays instead.

Comment: i want something like this but i dont want to put list inside the echo i want to put the id's list on toher file

Comment: Just include the other file with `include 'filename.php'`. Assuming your variables are in "FileA.php" and you need them in "FileB.php". Just add `include FileA.php` to "FileB.php". Then you can access the variables of "FileA.php" in "FileB.php".